# What's the current way to include jQuery in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I've been working with jQuery for a while now, and can't seem to figure out how to include the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries in my new Chrome Extension.

Can someone give em the correct method to include the jQuery libraries in my Extension? I tried a small bit of JSON code in my manifest, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://jquery.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery-1.7.1.js", "content.js"]
}
],
```

Am I using the current an/or correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"content_scripts": [ {
     "js": [ "jquery-1.7.1.js", "content.js" ],
     "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `matches` property specificies the URL's to inject your content-scripts files in to. So what you're doing now is injecting the `jquery-1.7.1.js` into `http://jquery.com/*`. In your case you should specify which URL's you want to inject, add the libraries you need in you Extension package and point to these files within the `"js":[]`.

If you want to add jQuery to your Options, Background or any other page within your Extension you can just add a `<script>` tag with a reference to the location like you would do on a regular HTML page.